# Body of page not shrinking at all, CSS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now I have a body with a width of 90%, and a left and right margin of 5%, and a border of 1px. Here's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make it so that when you zoom out all the way using ctr-, it'll shrink until it's a pin-prick in the middle of the page, but right now the body's width isn't shrinking at all when I zoom out all the way. It's staying the same size. Not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look at my code.

```
body {
width: 90%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

P.S: If you're not really understanding what I'm talking about, please either hit ctr-, or ctr and the scroll thing on your mouse until your page's size is around 25%. Do you see how stackoverflow is like a pin-prick smack-dab in the middle? Do you see the width of the entire site being shrunk down to that size? Well, when I do that, the body of my site doesn't shrink at all. It stays the same size.

Comment: Which is proportionally more, 90% of 100px or 90% of 10000px?

Comment: @MLeFevre Not understanding your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: frosty please provide any jsfiddle or demo so we can solve your issue in better way and quick. Thank you

Comment: You can set `max-width` to something like `1140px` etc.

Comment: Body of Stackoverflow page is also not shrinking, the content inside it do btw

Comment: @frosty Stackoverflow's content shrinks to "a pin-prick smack-dab in the middle" because the main `#content` part of it has a `width: 1000px`. So as you zoom out, it doesn't get any larger, it'll always remain 1000px. If you just have a width of 90%, it'll take up 90% of the available width.

Comment: @frosty You cannot achieve what you are asking here: browsers do not know the difference between enlarging a browser window (which should make your page wider) and zooming out (which should NOT make your page wider), since both will cause the "browser viewport" to gain in size. In what way should the browser know - or should you be able to intercept in your CSS - that the enlarged viewport is due to zooming, not just enlaring the window? Indeed, it is impossibru.

Comment: @MLeFevre Uhhh...Can you provide an example code for what you're explaining?

Comment: @BikasVaibhav Can you show me an example of how that can be accomplished? Thanks.

Comment: @frosty - Just put content inside the body and shrink that. That should work

Comment: @frosty please provide your jsfiddle or demo which is giving you issue. i asked you and again asking, no one will serve you ready made code. Please help us by explaining in detail about your issue with live demo. Thank you

Comment: @frosty That's how relative units work. If you set some size to 90%, that's what you get. Relative units are re-calculated every time you change the size of the window or change the scale factory.

Comment: @BikasVaibhav Um. It would be really nice if you provide an example. :) Please.

Comment: @frosty Percentages are relative values, http://jsfiddle.net/rqceo1xg/1/. If you give something a width of 90%, **it will always occupy 90% of the available width**, regardless if the width available is 10px, 100px, 100000000px, the result will always be the same, it will take up 90% of the width. If there is suddenly more width available to occupy, it'll readjust itself, and take up 90% of it. Zoom out? 90%. Zoom in? 90%. Throw that page on a custom monitor with dimensions 142930748923894234 x 458963457893485, it'll take up 90% of the available width.

Comment: @MLeFevre Okay. I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change % to px

```
body {
width: 1000px;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
border: 1px solid black;
 margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: What? I need my page to be 90%, and I need my margins to be 5%.

Comment: how width:1000px will make this page in center? width can be anything?

Comment: This will screw up the page and not even clsoe to the solution

Comment: margin:auto will make page in center

Comment: then read back. op said he is using 5% width in left and right.

Comment: For `margin:auto;` to work, it must be contained within a block of fixed width. :)

Comment: I need the default width to be 90%. Not 1000px. What if someone's screen size is smaller or larger than 1000px? Then it'll mess it up, won't it?

Comment: use css media query for this

Comment: @frosty What then is the difference between a larger screen and a zoomed-out browser? None, that is the answer! So how do you think your page can shrink when it's zoomed out when it may not shrink or grow when a screen differs in size?

Comment: @frosty if you write % values the browser makes that you are thinking is an error, but is not an error. You need to put values in PX if you need to shrink the page. Styling with this values `body` tag isn't recommended. You can write a `div` inside with the same.

Comment: @klaar I'm not really understanding what you're saying.

Comment: To check for smaller screen use chrome dev tool not zooming out.

Comment: @frosty If you define a relative value of viewport width to your page (in this case 90%), why are you at all surprised when it stays 90% even when you start to zoom? It is set to a  relative value, is it not? So it should be relative always. Zooming out will simulate a bigger screen, not just make everything smaller including the viewport. The window is the viewport; if that gets relatively bigger, so will the relative width of your page.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will fix your problem. Though best not using your body element as a wrapper. Use a div with the ID of wrapper like so.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    </div>
</body>
```

What this code does is sets the width to 90% so auto in margin property to take effect which centers your wrapper in the middle of their screen and uses border-box property so the border 1px width will not effect the layout, though you could use outline: 1px solid black if you do not want to use border-box.